# При нажатии на кнопку переместить Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, html

```
#msg div {
  position: relative;
  border: 3px solid #b75cff;
  height: 50px;
  top: 100px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 430px;
  left: 400px;
  font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, Arial;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 15px #b75cff;
}
```

При нажатии на кнопку появляются `div` элементы `msg`.

Цель: Чтобы при нажатии, старый `div` уходил вниз, а на его месте появлялся новый(чат).

```
<input type="button" id="MsgButton" value="Отправить" onclick="move();addMessage()" />
```

[image: 3 должен быть на месте первого]

3 должен быть на месте первого

Comment: а при чем здесь php ?

Comment: что должно быть в новом div ?

Comment: @Alex в каждом div`е появляется сообщение.

Answer (score 0):

Причем тут PHP?

```js
$("#MsgButton").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  var first_element_position = $(".div_1").top;
  var third_element_position = $(".div_3").top;

  //change the positions
  $(".div_1").css('top', third_element_position);
  $(".div_3").css('top', first_element_position);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="MsgButton" value="Отправить" onclick="move();addMessage()" />
<div class="div_1">1</div>
<div class="div_2">2</div>
<div class="div_3">3</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое) Но немного не то.
div неограниченное кол-во. Когда нажимается кнопка просто появляется новый div, под предыдущим.Мне всего лишь нужно, что бы появлялся над.

Comment: Алгоритм тот же. Только берем позицию не конкретного блока, а последнего - div:last-child

Comment: А если это окно чата - напишите просто
$(".main_div").append("<div class='new_msg'>" . msg . "</div>");
Где main_div это блок с сообщениями
Где new_msg это блок с самим сообщением, а переменная msg содержит в себе само сообщение

Comment: @AlexeyKhachatryan а проверить на работоспособность ?

Comment: @Alex Это пример

Comment: @AlexeyKhachatryan нерабочий "пример" не есть хорошо, т.к. публикуете его как ответ. это все равно как сказать *можно сделать так, но так не работает, в общем что-то в этом роде*. **[Вопрос — ответ. Ничего лишнего](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour)**

Comment: @Alex Сам вопрос довольно смазанный, так что любая помощь приветствуется.

Comment: @Аганим да вы что? Вам стоит внимательно ознакомиться с [ознакомительным туром](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) и со [справкой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help). [**Отвечайте на хорошо заданные вопросы**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), а для уточнений есть поле комментариев под вопросом.